# Command prompt from C# get stuck

Tags: c#, cmd

I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487972/run-command-prompt-from-c-sharp-twice) the other day, but neither I had an answer nor could I made it work. So I tried to slim it down as it was a lot of noise in the question.

Thing is, if I expose in a web api a all to a method that runs cmd.exe it works fine if I don't call it two times per request.

I mean, this code works fine:

```
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRunner _runner;

    public FilesController(IRunner runner)
    {
        _runner = runner;
    }

    public string Get()
    {
        return _runner.GetFiles();
    }
}

public class Runner : IRunner
{
    public Runner()
    {
        //var cd = @"cd C:\DummyFolder";
        //RunCmdPromptCommand(cd);
    }

    public string GetFiles()
    {
        var dir = @"cd C:\DummyFolder & dir";
        //var dir = "dir";
        return RunCmdPromptCommand(dir);
    }

    private string RunCmdPromptCommand(string command)
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                FileName = @"cmd.exe",
                Arguments = string.Format("/C {0}", command)
            }
        };

        process.Start();
        var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        process.WaitForExit();

        return output;
    }
}
```

But if I uncomment the lines commented (and obviously comment out the first line of `GetFiles`, when the code reaches for the second time (i.e. with "dir") the `RunCmdPromptCommand` it gets stuck in the line where it tries to read the standard error.

I don't know why, and I don't know how to force the exit whenever it could happen (might be other scenarios that can happen)

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the:

```
process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Is a synchronous operation.

Excerpt from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The redirected StandardError stream can be read synchronously or
>   asynchronously. Methods such as Read, ReadLine, and **ReadToEnd** perform
>   **synchronous** read operations on the error output stream of the process.
>   These synchronous read operations **do not complete** until the associated
>   Process *writes to its StandardError stream, or closes the stream*.

In other words, as long as the process doesn't write any standard error or closes the stream, it will get stuck there forever.

To fix this, I recommend to use Async [BeginErrorReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline(v=vs.110).aspx). Excerpt from MSDN:

> In contrast, **BeginErrorReadLine** starts **asynchronous** read operations on
>   the StandardError stream. This method enables a designated event
>   handler for the stream output and immediately returns to the caller,
>   which **can perform other work while the stream output is directed to the event handler**.

Which I think will be suitable for your need.

To use that. the example given in the MSDN is pretty straightforward. Check out especially these lines:

```
 netProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(NetErrorDataHandler); //note this event handler add

if (errorRedirect) //in your case, it is not needed
{
    // Start the asynchronous read of the standard
    // error stream.
    netProcess.BeginErrorReadLine(); //note this
}
```

And how to define the event handler:

```
private static void NetErrorDataHandler(object sendingProcess, 
    DataReceivedEventArgs errLine)
{
    // Write the error text to the file if there is something
    // to write and an error file has been specified.

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errLine.Data))
    {
        if (!errorsWritten)
        {
            if (streamError == null)
            {
                // Open the file.
                try 
                {
                    streamError = new StreamWriter(netErrorFile, true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not open error file!");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                }
            }

            if (streamError != null)
            {
                // Write a header to the file if this is the first
                // call to the error output handler.
                streamError.WriteLine();
                streamError.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                streamError.WriteLine("Net View error output:");
            }
            errorsWritten = true;
        }

        if (streamError != null)
        {
            // Write redirected errors to the file.
            streamError.WriteLine(errLine.Data);
            streamError.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used basically that example (just basically wrote to two stringbuilders for both the error and the output nstead of to a file)

Comment: @mitomed hei, great! Glad to know that you solve your issue. ;)

Comment: if you just need to ie log: `c.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
c.OutputDataReceived += (_, l) => { Log(l.Data); };
c.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
c.ErrorDataReceived += (_, l) => { Log(l.Data); };
`